# Static object that is accessible to all users like Application.cfc

Tags: php, coldfusion, application.cfc

I've done a fair bit of PHP over the years but I'm currently learning ColdFusion and have come across the `Application.cfc` file.

Basically this is a class that's created once (has an expire date). The class handles incoming users and can set session variables and static memory objects, such as queries. For example I can load site wide statistical data for one user in another thread from the `Application.cfc`. Something that would usually take a few seconds for each page would make the whole site quick and responsive.

Another example (just for clarification).
If I put an incremental variable that's set to 0 in `OnApplicationStart` this variable can be incremented with each user request (multiple users) or in `OnSessionStart` without the need to contact the SQL database since it's constantly in the server's memory under this application.

I was wondering if PHP has a similar file or object? Something that can be created once and used to store temporary variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PHP runtime itself initializes the environment from scratch on every HTTP request, so it has no built-in mechanism to do this. Of course you can [serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) anything into common storage and then read it back and deserialize on each request, but this is not the same as keeping it in-memory.

This type of functionality in PHP is achieved by outsourcing to other programs; [memcached](http://memcached.org/) and [APC](http://pecl.php.net/package/APC) are two of the most commonly used programs that offer such services, and [both](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.memcached.php) [come](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php) with PHP extensions that simplify working with them.